# UICollectionView inside UITableView with dynamic input (UICollectionView )

Tags: uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Hi I am using `UICollectionView` that shows the input values to be entered in an array. But, the problem is that I am using a `customCell` of the `UICollectionView` inside Custom `UITableViewCell`. It has the problem of when the `UITableView` is scrolled, The number of items getting changed and the number of items not displaying properly. I've tried few third party classes like `AFTabledCollectionView` and `HorizontalCollectionView`. Please help me

```
//View Controller Class

 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     return ar.count;
 }

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    CustomCells *cell = (CustomCells *)\[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier\];
                ;
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCells alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"\];
    }

    cell.lbl.text = @"Test";
    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:[[self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]count] forKey:@"r"];
    cell.routelbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Route %d",(int)indexPath.row+1];
    // ... set up the cell here ...
    cell.layer.cornerRadius=5;
    cell.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    return cell;
}

// Custom TableViewCell 

- (void)awakeFromNib {

 [self.collectionview reloadData];

 ViewController *v=[[ViewController alloc] init];

 NSLog(@"temp %d  %d ",temp,v.array.count);

 f=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 temp=(int)[f integerForKey:@"r"];
        ar=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [ar addObject:@"3"];
        [ar addObject:@"4"];
        [ar addObject:@"2"];
        [ar addObject:@"1"];


 UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
 flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
        flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(70, 91.0);
     //   \[self.collectionview setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout\];

 [self.collectionview registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCollectionViewCells" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell2"];
 self.collectionview.layer.cornerRadius=5;
 self.collectionview.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
        // Initialization code
 }

 - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
     [super setSelected:selected animated:animated\];

     // Configure the view for the selected state
 }

 -(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSLog(@"temp %d mm ",temp);
    return temp;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    return 1;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    temp=(int)indexPath.row;
    CustomCollectionViewCells *cell = (CustomCollectionViewCells *)\[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell2" forIndexPath:indexPath\];
    cell.layer.cornerRadius=5;
    cell.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    return cell;
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"%d",(int)indexPath.row);
}
```

The issue that I am facing is making number of items in the `UICollectionView` dynamic and discrete and also structuring the array. i.e Add new `UITableViewCell` and `UICollectionViewCell` with both addition and deletion.

Answer (score 0):

UICollectionView inside UITableView works perfect when the number of rows in a table is set to be 1 and number of sections in a row is set to be NSArray's count